# Appliction throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0 after deleting item

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My application throw  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0  after deleting item
The code of fragment which provide that:

```
 package jvs.com.notes.fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import jvs.com.notes.R;

import static jvs.com.notes.R.id.etNewItem;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NoteFragment extends Fragment {
private ArrayList<String>items;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
    private ListView lvItems;
    //we create this variable for using with different elements
    private View root;
    private Bundle savedState = null;

    public NoteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note,container,false);
        initView();
        readItems();
        //setup remove listener method
        setupListViewListener();

        return root;
    }
    //Initializing of view
private void initView(){
    lvItems =(ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    //creating adapter for viewing list of notes
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
  //  items.add("First Item");
 //   items.add("Second Item");
    //initializing button add Note
    Button b =(Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
    b.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);

}
//When we use fragment we have to use onClickListener
private View.OnClickListener mButtonClickListener=new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        onAddItem();
    }
};
//method for  adding Items
public  void onAddItem(){
    //initialisation of view for adding notes
    EditText etNewItem =(EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
    itemsAdapter.add(itemText);
    etNewItem.setText(" ");
    writeItems();
}

//When the item is long clicked it removes item
private void setupListViewListener(){
    //attaching a long click listener to the listview
    lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                               View item,int pos,long id){
                  items.remove(pos);
                    //Refresh the adapter
                    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    writeItems();
                    //Return true consumes the long click event(marks it handled)
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );
}
//method for writing and reading notes from file
    private void readItems(){
        File filesDir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            items = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
        }catch (IOException e){
            items =new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }
    private void writeItems() {
        File filesDir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, items);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

After deleting of item app shut down and in log it show such information:

```
6-26 23:24:27.496 30994-30994/jvs.com.notes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: jvs.com.notes, PID: 30994
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
       at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
       at jvs.com.notes.fragments.NoteFragment$2.onItemLongClick(NoteFragment.java:91)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3575)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3521)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

91 line belongs to items.remove(pos);

Comment: Do you have a way of knowing what is in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming the list has elements to remove, exception shows collection with 0 elements at the time you attempted to remove the element at index `1`.

```
Invalid index 1, size is 0
       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
       at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
```

There is probably an exception taking place here, and since you simply have it to instantiate the collection to a new empty collection, you get the exception when attempting to remove...

```
 private void readItems(){
        File filesDir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            items = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
        }catch (IOException e){
            //Write some logs here... Exception probably happens here
            //But you will never know since you are ignoring it.
            items =new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**: Corrected your `NoteFragment`, the trick is to keep both of your collections in sync at all times since you are not using a `CustomAdapter`. What I mean by this is, `items` and `itemsAdapter` need to be exact. If you remove an item you remove it from both and save `items` to the device. Same for when you add, you add to both and save `items` to the device.

```
public class NoteFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
    private ListView lvItems;
    private List<String> items;
    //we create this variable for using with different elements
    private View root;
    private Bundle savedState = null;

    public NoteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note,container,false);
        initView();
        setupListViewListener();

        return root;
    }
    //Initializing of view
private void initView(){
    lvItems =(ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    //creating adapter for viewing list of notes
    List<String> populatedList = readItems();
    items = new ArrayList<>(populatedList);

    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populatedList);
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    Button b =(Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
    b.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
}

//When we use fragment we have to use onClickListener
private View.OnClickListener mButtonClickListener=new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        onAddItem();
    }
};

//method for  adding Items
public  void onAddItem(){
    //initialisation of view for adding notes
    EditText etNewItem =(EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
    itemsAdapter.add(itemText);
    items.add(itemText);
    etNewItem.setText(" ");
    writeItems();
}

//When the item is long clicked it removes item
private void setupListViewListener(){
    //attaching a long click listener to the listview
    lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                               View item,int pos,long id){
                    //Remove the item within array at position
                    itemsAdapter.remove(itemsAdapter.getItem(pos));
                    items.remove(pos);
                    //Refresh the adapter
                    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    writeItems();
                    //Return true consumes the long click event(marks it handled)
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );
}
//method for writing and reading notes from file
    private List<String> readItems(){
        File filesDir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");

        try {
            return new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    private void writeItems() {
        File filesDir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, items);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Now its won"t remove the item, nothings happens

Comment: in log I have this

Comment: 06-27 14:18:49.257 816-827/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel           java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:14643)                                                                                at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2469)

Comment: @ВасильЄвсеєнко It's telling you that a permission is required, this means that you need to add it to your manifest and also request the permission explicitly via code.

Comment: I've added that permission to manifest file. And my API is 17. Do I need that code to my activity if API level is 17?

Comment: @ВасильЄвсеєнко Nope, only required for `API 23+`, give it a shot.

Comment: its still hut down when I try to delete my note

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Comment: @ВасильЄвсеєнко Corrected your code, you needed to load your data on int and populate the list. You also needed to remove elements from the adapter and from your local list and making sure to save the items list after every delete and write.

Comment: @ВасильЄвсеєнко NOTE: I submitted a pull request to update your file - https://github.com/Yevseyenko/Notes/pull/1

Answer (score 0):

It was seriously difficult to point out the issue, because all your items are having kind of similar names, try to use different names for your objects, it's just a suggestion let's come to the point:

The issue is here in your code:

```
 //method for  adding Items
public  void onAddItem(){
//initialisation of view for adding notes
EditText etNewItem =(EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
itemsAdapter.add(itemText); // Here is the issue
etNewItem.setText(" ");
writeItems();
}
```

The issue is that you are adding a item in your "itemAdpater" and not in your "items" arraylist, but when you are removing it you are trying to remove it from "items" arraylist. Where it doesn't even exist. Replace your method given above with this code:

```
//method for  adding Items
public  void onAddItem(){
//initialisation of view for adding notes
EditText etNewItem =(EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
items.add(itemText);
itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
etNewItem.setText(" ");
writeItems();
}
```

Hope it will work!

Comment: I dont have problems with adding items, its work good. I have problems with removing items. Application shut down after longClick on Item.

Comment: It's because in removing item it doesn't find anything to remove.The main issue is in AddItem that causes remove item to fail.just replace this code and everything will work fine.

Comment: Still shut down

Comment: Yes its still the same error, also I have error when I try to add new note

Comment: There must be something missing at somewhere. Can you give me your complete code, so I can debug it and see where is the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to put notifyDataSetChanged() after removing position instead use notifyItemRemoved(position) or notifyItemRangeRemoved(position) in your code and try